# Terminal showing object but not values

Tags: ruby, object

Running this code ...

```
class List
  attr_reader :all_tasks

  def initialize
     @all_tasks = []
  end

  def add(task)
    all_tasks.push(task)
  end

  def show
    all_tasks
  end
end

class Task
  attr_reader :description

  def initialize(description)
    @description = description
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  my_list = List.new

  my_list.add(Task.new("FIRST"))
  puts my_list.all_tasks
  my_list.add(Task.new("SECOND"))
  my_list.add(Task.new("THIRD"))

  puts "Next line is my_list.show execution:"
  puts my_list.show
end
```

... I get the following Terminal output:

```
#<Task:0x007fb24b08fed0>
Next line is my_list.show execution:
#<Task:0x007fb24b08fed0>
#<Task:0x007fb24b08fdb8>
#<Task:0x007fb24b08fd68>
```

My question is, why am I not seeing the *values* of the array stored in **my_list**? (If I understand programming vernacular correctly, the output of Terminal is the *object itself*, not the values stored in the object. Am I understanding that right?)

Comment: What is your verbosity level?

Comment: Oh wait, this is because Task does not have `to_s` overridden. Alias `representation` to `to_s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#<Task:0x007fb24b08fed0>
```

means an instance of class `Task`, or in other words, a `Task` object.
It has id `0x007fb24b08fed0`.

This is the standard Ruby representation for objects that don't answer to `to_s` method.

You could just define `Task#to_s`, which is called by `puts` :

```
class Task
  def to_s
    @description
  end
end
```

The output becomes :

```
FIRST
Next line is my_list.show execution:
FIRST
SECOND
THIRD
```

Note : If you call `Task#inspect`, you see the class, the object id and the defined instance variables.

```
puts task.inspect
#<Task:0x00000002657af0 @description="FIRST">
```

Answer (score 2):

It is doing exactly what you are telling it to do, which is `show`. Your show method returns the array of tasks, hence an array of objects. Modify your show method as such

```
def show
  all_tasks.each do |task|
     puts task.description
  end
end
```

This will return each task description.

Just change the last line from `puts my_list.show` to `my_list.show`, as the puts is already in the show method.

Comment: Note that if you use this approach you would just do `my_list.show` not `puts my_list.show`.

Comment: @EliSadoff Edited Answer

Comment: Oh, okay, I see, Leo: So, my code is indeed returning the array, which is an array of Objects (since each instance of the Task class is an Object, not just a value; and therefore `my_list.all_tasks` is an array of Objects).

Comment: @pgayed correct, you need to call the property(which is description in this case) of the object(Task) as well.

Comment: Note that List shouldn't know how Task should be displayed, Task should know it!